# Android Animated Vector Drawable: change at runtime

Tags: android, animation, vector

Using android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton a vector animation (rotate and morph) works perfectly if set from the layout xml, but not from runtime.

Working:

```
android:src="@drawable/vector_anim_play_to_stop"
```

Not working:

```
floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector_anim_play_to_stop)
```

it does not animate correctly when set from runtime, it does the rotate animation but not the morph. How is that possible?

in both cases I am starting the animation with:

```
    Animatable animatable = (Animatable) floatingActionButton.getDrawable();
    animatable.start();
```

Comment: use `setImageDrawable` instead of `setImageResource`

Comment: man, that's simple :) thanks! Please add it as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create your `Animated Vector Drawable` by using static `create()` method and call `setImageDrawable()` instead of `setImageResource()`